# Is it possible for MLKit to detect the 3D dimensions of an object?

Tags: android, machine-learning, object-detection, google-mlkit

From what I've used so far and know, Google's ML Kit api offers support for Object-Detection & Tracking, Face Detection, Image Labeling, etc. However, in each of these use cases, it seems to only get a basic 2D render that can product a Rect bounding box and nothing else.

[image: example: it can scan the apple, and return it's 2D coordinates. But not it's 3D coordinates in space.]

Unless I'm mistaken, is it possible for MLKit to track objects in 3D fashion - as in, instead of just producing a 2D rectangle box, it can produce a three-dimensional bounding box with length, width, and height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, ML Kit's Object Detection and Tracking API only works 2D. 3D is not supported yet.

Comment: So would it be best to combine it with ARCore?